# Have to open twice for the data to show using angular-strap modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap

I'm having a problem using angular-strap modal. I'm trying to fetch a data using $http and display its result into the modal. The weird part is I have to open the modal twice for the data to appear/display. I have this code below:

```
.controller('ModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', 'Api', function(scope, modal, Api) {
  scope.open = function (gameId) {

    Api.getGameByGameId(gameId).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            scope.items = result.data;
        }, function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

    var modalInstance = modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      resolve: {
        items: function () {        
          return scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        console.log(selectedItem);
      scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        console.log('Modal dismissed');
    });
  };
}])
.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'items', function(scope, modalInstance, items) {
    console.log(items);
    scope.items = items;
}])
```

Using firebug console, I figured that its firing first the console_log(items) before the console.log(result) in my $http call. So when I open again the modal it then show the data. How do I sync my $http so when it will be the first thing to be invoke?

Comment: Are you resolving the promise when the $http call returns? And also make sure you are returning a promise from your service.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured it out. Solved my own problem.

Here my solution:

```
var getGameDetail = {
        async: function() {
            var promise = Api.getGameByGameId(gameId).then(function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                    return result.data;
                }, function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }); 
                return promise;
        }
    };
```